# Django 1.3 staticfiles + django-compressor + CloudFront

Tags: python, django, amazon-cloudfront

We're looking at using Django 1.3's staticfiles + django-compressor to get our media on CloudFront. However, we're having a hard time figuring out the best way to prepend a unique cache buster to the final URL so we don't have to muck with creating new distributions or invalidation requests.

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this with staticfiles+django-compressor? For example,

```
/aks290209sdlk/media/css/base.css
```

Each time we deploy, change the hash:

```
/fslk39sod/media/css/base.css
```

This means that the {% static %} template tags will also need to be aware of the change. We've got multiple app servers, so whatever we do needs to stay in sync between them.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the issue; django-compressor automatically names files with a hash based on either the file's mtime or calculated from its contents (user-definable). They actually recommend using the file's contents if you're going to be deploying your static files to a CDN, since the mtime will likely vary depending on the server being used at the moment. Either way, changing the file will result in a completely new filename, so there's effectively no cache to bust.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer to your question, but because you say that you're evaluating asset managers, it's not quite off-topic.

I don't know django-compressor well, but personally I find other asset managers easier/nicer to use. You can pick one from: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/ depending on your specific needs. I'm using [django-mediagenerator](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator) which is very simple to use yet powerful. First you define media bundles in your settings.py:

```
MEDIA_BUNDLES = (
    ('main.css',
        'css/reset.css',
        'css/design.css',
    ),
    ('main.js',
        'js/jquery.js',
        'js/jquery.autocomplete.js',
    ),
)
```

Then you define media processing path, also in settings.py:

```
ROOT_MEDIA_FILTERS = {
    'js': 'mediagenerator.filters.yuicompressor.YUICompressor',
    'css': 'mediagenerator.filters.yuicompressor.YUICompressor',
}
```

-- you can combine scripts, compress then, merge into one file, add hash to them etc.

Then you just call: `./manage.py generatemedia` and voila (well, not quite - there are a few more settings you have to type in your settings.py, but nothing hard to figure out).

In the templates it looks like this:

```
{% include_media 'main.css' media='screen,print' %}
<img src="{% media_url 'some/image.png' %}" />
```

As you can see this is the reverse of django-compressor approach - here you define your assets upfront in settings.py and then reference them.

Comment: Ugh. Not having to list out each and every one of your static files in your settings.py file is one of the chief benefits of using django-compressor. Whoever thought that would be a good idea in the first place is a sadist.

Comment: @Chris: If you want to start a flame war then let's move to chat :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly have DEBUG set to True? I believe django-compressor only does the hashing when DEBUG=False.